# How do I create a subclass of a generic class with more restrictive types?

Tags: java, generics

This class is intended to represent a pair of objects of arbitrary types - what a python dev might think of as a 2-tuple.

```
public class Pair<DD extends Comparable<DD>,VV> implements Comparable< Pair<DD,VV> > {
    DD d;
    VV v;
    // Implementation removed.
    }
```

I want to make a new subclass called NumberPair - the only difference is that while **Pair** can conceivably contain any two classes of object, my **NumberPair class will only be allowed to contain numbers**.

Can anybody tell me how to express this?

PS. Admittedly this looks like a silly design given that anywhere we might use this class we could also use a Map - please ignore that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely get the problem, but I think this might be what you're looking for:

```java
public class NumberPair<NDD extends Number & Comparable<NDD>, NVV extends Number> extends Pair<NDD, NVV> {}
```

This forces both type parameters to extend Number.

Comment: Yes, this is the one I want. @JustYo's solution was correct but I guess I had mis-stated the question. I dont want to loose the ability to tie it down to a spesific implementation of number, but I do want it to fail if somebody creates an instance with anything that is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

This is declaration:

```
public class NumberPair<VV> extends Pair<Number,VV> {

}
```